# Prestashop 1.7.6 - Current Admin Theme CSS Overrides

Tags: prestashop

am trying to modify the PS 1.7 admin theme css, mostly just to highlight a test environment vs production, but also for a few colour changes.

I modified ./adminFolder/themes/default/css/override.css

However this only works for "old" pages. More and more pages are using the "New-Theme" and not "Default" in the Back Office. The Default theme has a CSS override file, but the New Theme does not.

How do we create such an override in the new theme folder?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you need to add your CSS to the back office using `actionAdminControllerSetMedia` and `Controller::addCSS` method.

Example:
https://github.com/PrestaShop/blockwishlist/blob/dev/blockwishlist.php#L123

This way, a new CSS will be added after the new theme's CSS so you can override every rule.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to overrride the setMedia function like this :

**override/classes/controller/AdminController.php**

```
<?php
class AdminController extends AdminControllerCore
{
    public function setMedia($isNewTheme = false)
    {
        parent::setMedia($isNewTheme);
        $this->addCSS(__PS_BASE_URI__ . $this->admin_webpath . '/themes/default/css/overrides.css', 'all', 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll give this a go! If i understand, this is using the default theme css override even for "new-theme"?